# Unparsed Markdown in blog post "Ask like a human: Implementing semantic search on Stack Overflow"

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, blog

[Here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/31/ask-like-a-human-implementing-semantic-search-on-stack-overflow/) is the blog post I'm referring to.

See this paragraph (link ommitted from paragraph as it isn't relevant here)

> Building on the work we did to build course recommendations, we used the same pipeline from our Azure Databricks data platform that fed into a pre-trained BERT model from the `SentenceTransformers` library to [...]

It looks like that was intended to be code-formatting, but if it was meant to be a quote, I'd suggest [proper quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#quotation-marks). I'm assuming it was just unparsed markdown, though.

Could this be fixed, please?

Comment: "to programmers seeking accurate, logically correct answers to their questions, what good is an LLM that hallucinates?" Looks like they finally understand, ugh.

Comment: @bobeyt6isstricken [do they really though](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425787/11107541)?

Comment: @starball: Obviously not, because that blog post wraps up with Generative AI.  Stack Exchange answers are not chapter-length documents that need summarization.  A list of links to the most relevant Q&As is the proper output of a search engine, and AI ought to be able to improve those without changing the output format.  (It would not be a "generative AI")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for flagging this; we fixed the markdown in the blog there.