# Errors in blog post "Ask like a human: Implementing semantic search on Stack Overflow"

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, spelling, grammar

I probably should have included these earlier, but I didn’t realize at the time of posting. I also realize this post is rather nit-picky, but most, if not all, of these are valid issues anyways.

[Here is the blog post I'm referring to.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/31/ask-like-a-human-implementing-semantic-search-on-stack-overflow/)

Right before the heading The old ways: Lexical, there are two periods, which is odd. I’d suggest a single period instead.

The sentence "We could choose between a ..." needs the word "model" after open source. Also, closed-source is hyphenated, whereas open source is not, which seems odd. This occurs in several places.

The next paragraph needs a period before "Because embedding models"

After the table, the caption/disclaimer should use "over time" instead of "overtime"

Under the first sentence below AI and the future, consider swapping the colon and the comma.

Also, Grammarly caught this:

> Said another way, if you think of the search space as a city, terms with closely related meaning or sentiment will live in the same or adjacent neighborhoods.

"meaning" and "sentiment" should be plural for agreement with "terms"

Could the blog post be updated to correct these errors?

Comment: Your previous bug report about the same blog post: [Unparsed Markdown in blog post "Ask like a human: Implementing semantic search on Stack Overflow"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391821/335251)

Comment: See also [Broken table in "Ask like a human: Implementing semantic search on Stack Overflow" blog post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426624/broken-table-in-ask-like-a-human-implementing-semantic-search-on-stack-overflo) on MSO

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned the comments by Jnat, the issues were fixed in November 2023. I looked through them today and can acknowledge this.

I write this motivated by [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396043/please-post-an-answer-upon-status-completed) recommending to use answers instead of a comments for bugs which were fixed.

Comment: Please make this a Community Wiki (there's checkbox you can tick when posting or editing answer), thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda: thanks for the reminder, fixed it.